# Having issue with mod_rewrite on openlitespeed

Tags: mod-rewrite, directadmin, openlitespeed

I can't seem to get rewrite engine to work on my web server openlitespeed.

I have checked openlitespeed web login and it says it is on. I have also tried restarting openlitespeed couple times now.

I am using .htaccess to test rewrite rule but it's not working. Here is what I have in the file

RewriteRule ^/helloWorld/$ /index.php

I have checked the logs but so far nothing there I just keep getting 404 error when loading the website. when it should be sending my to index.php when I try to reach domain.com/HelloWorld

I have tried checking error logs but nothing there?

I have also tried other browser in private mode.

I have also restart openlitespeed couple times now.

Comment: The rule you shared is to redirect /helloWorld/ to index.php which is not what you are looking for. If you want to auto detect the index.php for everypafe, please check the web admin > General > Index Files, make srue you have index.php value in the Index Files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am honestly just trying to make sure rewrite works correctly. Before I install a script on my server that says it requires Mod_rewrite

Comment: You cannot use RewriteRule as same as you use it in Apache/LiteSpeed server. Openlitespeed is a bit different from that. Check this: https://openlitespeed.org/kb/migrate-apache-rewrite-rules-to-openlitespeed/